# Default fields available in a Search Server web content source?

Tags: sharepoint, search-engine, field

I'm using the search web service on a Search Server 2008 Express install in a web application.

I have created the content source and scope and can successfully query the web service if I specify the fields I wish to return.

What I cannot find out is what fields are available to me, if I modify the query to "SELECT * ..." then I get an error that my query is malformed.

Can anyone tell me what fields are available by default for a web based search source?

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some good tools available to help you debug this, here are some suggestion:

1. My [SearchCoder](http://www.codeplex.com/MOSSSearchCoder) will help you right SQL Correctly
2. The [Search Service tool](http://sharepointsearchserv.codeplex.com/) helps you with the Web Services
3. There are some .NET helpers on MSDN here [Helper Classes for the SharePoint Server 2007 Search Query Web Service Built Using the Microsoft .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb852171.aspx)

And the [Search Community Toolkit](http://sct.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex. They should all get you moving.